# How much memory does a block hold?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-ds

Whenever I get a game on the E-Shop, it lets me know that said game takes a certain amount of blocks.

Sometimes it'll let me know I need to make room for more blocks to download some games.

How much memory is in a block?

Comment: It does tell you how many blocks you have left, if you are concerned about how much space you are using on the card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is the same as the information I found (and I would be surprised if it wasn't) for the [DSi](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/dsi/en_la/sdCards.jsp#blocks) and the [Wii](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/wii/en_na/ht_settings.jsp), one block is 128KB of data.